# Magento 2: I can't display the value of a custom product attribute in product page

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom, page

I want to show two product custom attributes in product view page side by side the price with the same format (font size).
The attributes are **PP** and **PR** witch I created in Magento Admin and assign to the product.

[image]

Next I tried to put the code in `list.phtml` to display the attributes:

[image]

I used

```
<?php echo 'PP ' . $_product->getData('pp') . ' PR ' . $_product->getData('pr'); ?>
```

But unfortunately I just can't retrieved the value of the attributes and it shows blank.
[image]

Could someone help me on this issue?

Comment: Have you re-index after new attributes?

Comment: Yes, I have had re-index.

Comment: Ok, I have added answer, please try and let mw know that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo 'PP '.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pp')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) . ' PR ' .     $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pr')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)?>
```

Also, check both attributes are `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront
Used in Product Listing`.

Answer (score 0):

$product->getCustomAttribute('pr')->getValue();

Answer (score 0):

> Here's an example of how you can display custom product attributes in the list.phtml template file:

```
     <?php
        $ppValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pp')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        $prValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pr')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
     ?>

    <?php if ($ppValue): ?>
       <div class="pp-attribute">
         <span class="label"><?php echo __('PP'); ?>:</span>
         <span class="value"><?php echo $ppValue; ?></span>
       </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($prValue): ?>
      <div class="pr-attribute">
         <span class="label"><?php echo __('PR'); ?>:</span>
         <span class="value"><?php echo $prValue; ?></span>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This code uses $ppValue and $prValue to retrieve the values of the pp and pr attributes respectively and then checks if they have values before displaying them.